# Unable to update a specific position in all the lines of a file using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, slice

I am trying to build a script with below functionality,

> Take Input from User, a) FileName b) Specific Position to
>   Update/Modify c) New Value

Input File would be as below,

> uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu
>   iiiiiiii hhhhhhh iiii
>   iiiiiiiii
>   iiiiiiiiiiiiiiii tttttttttttttttttt

I managed to do the above for the First Line of the File ONLY (without taking input from User)

```
import os,mmap
InputFile=os.open("testt.txt",os.O_RDWR)
Line=mmap.mmap(InputFile,0)
Line[4:9]="44444"
os.close(InputFile)
```

When I try the same to Update Second Line `Line=mmap.mmap(InputFile,1)` , struck with the below error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/Scripts/Test.py", line 10, in <module>
    Line[4:9]="44444"
IndexError: mmap slice assignment is wrong size
>>>
```

Looking forward for suggestion/help to get this done.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `os.open` instead of the built in function `open()`

Comment: @Professor_Joykill: no reason as such.. :)

Comment: can you please more elaborate what you want to do ?

Comment: @AkshaySingh: I would like to take input (Position Of Line/Index) & 'New Value to update' from User and apply to the File and save it.
ex: Input File= testt.txt, Line= First Line, 5-Position to 9-Position, NewValue = "Updat" and save the InputFile(testt.txt)

Comment: How would the user specify the position? Would it be a line number, or something in the line?

Comment: Line Number & Index  (ex:- Line:2 Col:33)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the file **abc.txt** and **main.py** file in same directory

Content of **abc.txt** before running **main.py script** :

```
aaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbb
ccccccccc
```

Content of **main.py**

```
line = input()
first_position = input()
second_position = input()
datav = raw_input()
with open('abc.txt','r+') as f:
    data = map(str,f.read().split('\n'))
    change = data[line-1][:first_position] + ''.join(datav) + data[line-1][second_position:]
    data[line-1] = change
    with open('abc.txt','w+') as t:
        for i in data:
            t.write(i+'\n')
```

---

```
**Custom input**

1

2

7

bbbbbb
```

---

```
**Sample output** as expected it is saved in the file abc.txt:


aabbbbbaa

bbbbbbbbb

ccccccccc
```

Comment: Amazing, it worked just as required :) ...thanks a ton!

Comment: Appreciated dear

Comment: How about passing the input (Line, FirstPosition, SecondPosition & NewValue) from an excel for 10-set of data..would that work using any excel module such as 'openpyxl' or 'pandas'?

Comment: do you want to read the data from a excel file  and do some computation ?

Comment: For the same script, I would like to pass the Input (Line, FirstPosition, SecondPosition & NewValue) from an excel and update the txt-file

Comment: I want to pass each Cell.Value from three different Columns (Line, FirstPosition, SecondPosition, NewValue) into the..line = input()
first_position = input()
second_position = input() ...iterate it and save it into a txt-file

Comment: I want to iterate the below for all the data from excel --  `wb = load_workbook(filename = 'Test1.xlsx')
sheet_ranges = wb['Sheet1']
print(sheet_ranges['B1'].value)
line = sheet_ranges['A1'].value
first_position = sheet_ranges['B1'].value
second_position = sheet_ranges['C1'].value
datav = sheet_ranges['D1'].value
with open('testt.txt','r+') as f:
    data = map(str,f.read().split('\n'))
    change = data[line-1][:first_position] + ''.join(datav) + data[line-1][second_position:] data[line-1] = change
    with open('test01.txt','w+') as t:for i in data:t.write(i+'\n')`